# Cloudformation template to SAM or serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-sam-cli

I want to extend [lambCI cloudformation template](https://github.com/lambci/lambci/blob/master/lambci.template) but am finding myself lost in barley human-readable json/yml it provides.

Is it possible to reverse-transform CF template to something else(sam, serverless...), edit it and then transform back?

Comment: Looks like it was written by hand, so I think the answer would be no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That template is not really complicated. Having it as a SAM-template wouldn't make it more readable at all, because the ressources it defines either can't be defined using SAM or wouldn't make it significantly shorter.

As far as I know there are also no tools available which would do conversion to SAM/Serverless automatically.

I always find such templates way more readable in YAML, than in JSON, so what you could do is to convert it from JSON to YAML using [aws-cfn-template-flip](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip), edit it and convert it back afterwards (or even use it as YAML).

Answer (score 0):

to convert json to yaml, just use this site (or one like it) https://www.json2yaml.com/